# Pandas add columns error must be same length as key?

Tags: python, pandas

I got this error when I try to split one column and create additional columns in current dataframe:

Columns must be same length as key

```
if 'FULLNAME' in dataset.columns:
       dataset[['FIRSTNAME','LASTNAME']] = dataset.FULLNAME.str.split(" ", 1)
```

Before I set static columns names:

```
dataset.columns = ["NUM", "MMYY", "AGE", "FULLNAME", "ADDRESS", "CITY", "STATE", "ZIP", "COUNTRY", "PHONE"]
```

How to fit it?

I suppose some of columns has not `FULLNAME` to extract

**May be to use this:**

```
dataset["FIRSTNAME"] = None
dataset["LASTNAME"] = None

if 'FULLNAME' in dataset.columns:
    r = dataset.FULLNAME.str.split(" ", 1)
    if (r[0]):
        dataset["LASTNAME"] = r[0]
    if (r[1]):
        dataset["FIRSTNAME"] = r[1]
```

Dataset is:

```
"NUM", "MMYY", "AGE", "FULLNAME", "ADDRESS", "CITY", "STATE", "ZIP", "COUNTRY", "PHONE"

1 1010 18 OLEG Kirova Wage US 1911 US +9584345345
2 1011 19 Krina Kirova Wage US 1911 US +9584345345
3 1012 20 Marina Kirova Wage US 1911 US +9584345345
```

Comment: This is a great example of where you need to provide us with sample data that we can use to recreate the issue.

Comment: What is `dataset`? You should provide a fully reproducible example otherwise we'll just make random guesses

Comment: I have updated question with dataset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to pass expand=True into split so that it returns a DataFrame...

```
if 'FULLNAME' in dataset.columns:
       dataset[['FIRSTNAME','LASTNAME']] = dataset.FULLNAME.str.split(" ", 1, expand=True)
```

Comment: It works thank you! Could you help me, when I have rows with different columns count. How to show first line from each group?

Comment: I think you may need to post it in another question with more details.